# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int

I am currently learning Python so I have no idea what is going on.

```
num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))
num3 = int(input("What is your third number? "))
numlist = [num1, num2, num3]
print(numlist)
print("Now I will remove the 3rd number")
print(numlist.pop(2) + " has been removed")
print("The list now looks like " + str(numlist))
```

When I run the program, entering in numbers for num1, num2 and num3, it returns this:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a string and an integer, which is incorrect.

Change `print(numlist.pop(2)+" has been removed")` to any of these:

Explicit `int` to `str` conversion:

```
print(str(numlist.pop(2)) + " has been removed")
```

Use `,` instead of `+`:

```
print(numlist.pop(2), "has been removed")
```

String formatting:

```
print("{} has been removed".format(numlist.pop(2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

try,

`str_list = " ".join([str(ele) for ele in numlist])`

this statement will give you each element of your list in `string` format

`print("The list now looks like [{0}]".format(str_list))`

and,

change `print(numlist.pop(2)+" has been removed")` to

`print("{0} has been removed".format(numlist.pop(2)))`

as well.

Comment: `str(numlist)` does certainly *not* result in an exception (even though it might not be what OP is after).