# I can't convert my variable from integer to string

Tags: string, variables, python-2.7, integer

This is the code:

```
import time
import os
os.system("cls")
a=1
while True:
    if a>512:
        a=1
        print (a + " kb")
    if a<1024:
        print (a + " bytes")
    a *= 2
    time.sleep(.5)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "Sequence1.py", line 10, in <module>
>         print (a + " bytes")
>     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

If I changed it to a string then my if statements wouldn't work. Sorry if this question has been asked before. Thanks.

Comment: `"{0} bytes".format(a)`. :/

Comment: It might be useful to link the following sites.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441035/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you need `a` to be integer for you logic you need it as string just for presentational purposes. So convert it only when printing it. You have several ways to do that, as you certainly know. Some of them:

```
print('{0} bytes'.format(a))

print('%s bytes' % a)

print(str(a) + ' bytes')
```

Comment: Alright, I went with the third line, now how do I continue it saying kb after it?