# I am having a hard time understanding why am I getting this TypeError in Python

Tags: python, pygal

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

When my results generate perfect floats in my Python code:

```
data = ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)

0.12,0.29,0.13,0.12,0.23,0.13,0.07,0.21,0.22,0.18,0.11,0.18,0.16,0.07,0.20,
0.11,0.09,0.11,0.18,0.07,0.12,0.14,0.14,0.11,0.21,0.21,0.06,0.20,0.16,0.00,
0.14,0.12,0.04,0.10,0.12,0.13,0.11,0.21,0.22,0.08,0.11,0.12,0.08,0.00,0.13,
0.05,0.14,0.12,0.09,0.12,0.14,0.15,0.09,0.14,0.07,0.07,0.00,0.41,0.01,0.08,
0.08,0.09,0.10,0.21,...

@app.route('/main')
@login_required
def main():
    # Data from .csv file
    ######################
    base_dir = "db/"
    logged_in_user = g.user
    spreadsheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=os.path.join(base_dir, "example.csv"))
    house_index_data = [x.encode('ascii') for x in spreadsheet.column[48]]
    print ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)
    # data = str(house_index_data).replace("'", "")
    data = ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)

    # Graphs (Bar) data
    #####################
    bar_chart = pygal.StackedBar(fill=True, interpolate='cubic', style=BlueStyle)
    bar_chart.title = 'Stack bar chart of House Index'
    bar_chart.add('House Index',  [data])
    bar_chart.render()

    return render_template('main.html',
                           user=logged_in_user,
                           value=spreadsheet,
                           bar_chart=bar_chart,
                           line_chart=line_chart)
```

Comment: This would work, but the particular Library I am using requires either Floats or Int

Comment: It looks to me like the variable `data` you create is a string and when it is used, in `bar_char.add(...,[data])` it should be a list of floats. Should you be calling `bar_char.add(...,house_index_data)` instead?

Comment: Where exactly is the `TypeError` being raised, since you aren't using the `+` operator any where in your own code.

Comment: If you could tell where the error is raised, it would help people trying to help you. However, I think `data` is supposed to be a list of floats or int, which it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the problem:

```
house_index_data = [x.encode('ascii') for x in spreadsheet.column[48]]
```

`house_index_data` should be a [list of floats](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/bar.html) and you should be calling:

```
bar_chart.add('House Index', house_index_data)
```

So maybe:

```
house_index_data = [float(x.encode('ascii')) for x in spreadsheet.column[48]]
...
...
bar_chart.add('House Index', house_index_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, however the pure format 'house_index_data' generates this: ['0.2566', '0.522' ... ] etc, which is not the correct format for this Lib

Comment: That's why I suggest the: `float(x.encode('ascii'))`

Comment: Can you update the question to include the stack trace? That should confirm the line of reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441035/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str#answer-20441046)

Moreover you are doing the same thing multiple times; I'm referring to `data = ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)` and `print ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)`

You just have to print `data` and delete the `print ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)`

More or less your code will look like this:

```
@app.route('/main')
@login_required
def main():
    # Data from .csv file
    ######################
    base_dir = "db/"
    logged_in_user = g.user
    spreadsheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=os.path.join(base_dir, "example.csv"))
    house_index_data = [x.encode('ascii') for x in spreadsheet.column[48]]
    # data = str(house_index_data).replace("'", "")
    data = ",".join(str(x) for x in house_index_data)
    print data

    # Graphs (Bar) data
    #####################
    bar_chart = pygal.StackedBar(fill=True, interpolate='cubic', style=BlueStyle)
    bar_chart.title = 'Stack bar chart of House Index'
    bar_chart.add('House Index',  [data])
    bar_chart.render()

    return render_template('main.html',
                           user=logged_in_user,
                           value=spreadsheet,
                           bar_chart=bar_chart,
                           line_chart=line_chart)
```