# how do you find data from a file or list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I am trying to determine if a user is over 18 from data put in a list/file.

There is a problem under `def pulldata()` as well as `def enterdata()`. Here is the full code.

```
def enterdata():
    myFile=open("members.txt", "at")
    myList = []
    firstname = input("please enter first name")
    myList.insert(0,firstname)
    lastname = input("please enter last name")
    myList.insert(1,lastname)
    age = int(input("please enter age"))
    myList.insert(2,age)
    print (myList)
    for item in myList:
        myFile.write(str(item))
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
    userchoice()
def readfile():
    myFile=open('members.txt', 'r')
    details = myFile.read()
    print(details)
    myFile.close()
    userchoice()
def pulldata():
    myFile = open ("members.txt", "rt")
    myList = []
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        myList.append(line)
        print (myList)
    myFile = myList(map(int,age))       
    myFile.close
    userchoice()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\D\users.py", line 63, in <module> login() File "D:\D\users.py", line 10, in login userchoice() File "D:\D\users.py", line 24, in userchoice enterdata() File "D:\D\users.py", line 42, in enterdata myFile.write(item+" ") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: is registration.txt in the same folder as this python script? if not you need to specify the full path

Comment: the code is in the same folder as the txt file I am unable to pull specific data from the file under the def pulldata

Comment: this code is a little outdated I have made a few improvements since then if you could look at these and the error that was thrown

Comment: what is the traceback of the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\D\users.py", line 63, in <module>
    login()
  File "D:\D\users.py", line 10, in login
    userchoice()
  File "D:\D\users.py", line 24, in userchoice
    enterdata()
  File "D:\D\users.py", line 42, in enterdata
    myFile.write(item+" ")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: the code is different I will change it now

Comment: that is the new code above after changes have been made

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441035/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str)

Comment: Hint: `myFile.write(str(item)+" ")`

Comment: Like cricket said, the last part of your list is age, aka int. You need it to be a string

Comment: also age in pulldata is not defined because it is out of scope.

Comment: ok thank you here is what the code now threw when I edited it like this

Comment: myFile.write(str(item,' '))

Comment: File "D:\D\users.py", line 42, in enterdata
    myFile.write(str(item,' '))
TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: how would i sort out the code so that age is in scope

Comment: only wrap item in str() so like str(item) + " "

Comment: There are *many* problems with this `code`... not just the lack of `string` conversion

Comment: that has worked thank you

Comment: yes i am aware with the problems with this code this was a rough draft of the code my main problem is under def pull data if anyone could tell me how i would edit my code so that it will show all users over 18 and send a warning if a user is under 18

Comment: File "D:\D\users.py", line 28, in userchoice
    pulldata()
  File "D:\D\users.py", line 59, in pulldata
    myFile = myList(map(int,age))
NameError: name 'age' is not defined

Comment: this was now thrown by the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so to make this easier I changed the age value that goes into the file in enterdata() to `myList.insert(2," Age: " + str(age))`. The reason is so now you can do some string concatenation to grab the age out of the file like so:

```
myList = []
def enterdata():
    list = []
    firstname = input("please enter first name")
    list.insert(0,firstname)
    lastname = input("please enter last name")
    list.insert(1,lastname)
    age = int(input("please enter age"))
    list.insert(2," Age: " + str(age))
    myList.append(list)
    print (myList)
    userchoice()
def readfile():
    print(myList)
    userchoice()
def pulldata():
    Listof18Yrolds = []
    for id, line in enumerate(myList):
        age = str(line[2])
        age = age[age.rindex(':')+1:].replace(" ","")
        if int(age) >= 18:
            Listof18Yrolds.append(line)
            print(Listof18Yrolds)
    if len(Listof18Yrolds) >= 0:
        print("Users 18 and over..")
        print(Listof18Yrolds)
    else:
        print("Sorry all users are under 18.")
    userchoice()
```

To explain what is going on here, the line `age = str(line[line.rindex(':')+1:]).replace(" ","")` is pulling the characters after the colon to grab the age. This then needs to be trimmed of whitespace. to be able to convert to int later. Then you can check if the age is 18 and older and if so, add to the list.

EDIT: I removed the file stuff and moved myList = [] out of methods

EDIT: added the missing subroutine def pulldata()

**EDIT:**This is for Lists only. I removed all instances of Files since you removed the creation of the file. ****

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: Can you mark it as your answer if this helped? @ThePythonAmateur

Comment: I have just added this to my code and it has thrown the following error

Comment: line 56, in pulldata
    age = str(line[line.rindex(':')+1:]).replace(" ","")
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: did you change the enterData() line myList.insert(2," Age: " + str(age)) ? if you did what did you input. If you didn't then change it and try again @ThePythonAmateur

Comment: ok I am making alterations to the code and trying to make it print the list but it would not show the contents of the ocde

Comment: myList = []
    for line in myList:
        age = (str(line[line.rindex(':')+1:]).replace(" ",""))
        line = line.strip("\n")
        if int(age) >= 18:
            myList.append(line)
            print(myList)
    if len(myList) >= 0:
        print("Users 18 and over..")
        print(len(myList))
    else:
        print("Sorry all users are under 18.")

Comment: this is what the section look like now but it wont print the list I removed the my

Comment: can you update your question with your most recent code? @ThePythonAmateur

Comment: Okay so the reason you are getting an error is because you are creating two myLists. One in each method. So you fill one, and then in the next method you create another one and try to pull from it but it is empty. Since you took the file part out try moving myList = [] out of both methods and make it a global variable. Then you can add/delete/pull from any method inside that class. see code from my answer for details

Comment: 1) the subroutine which is called def pulldata() has been cut off in this code and it reads from a file and by removing the file part it cant read what is on the list                                                                                                             2) the same error is thrown

Comment: what do you mean by cut off? Why do you not want the file part anymore?

Comment: the full code has been edited and the subroutine has been removed from the original piece I will add it now so you could hopefully work around this thank you for your patience I am doing GCSE computing and haven't quite grasped python yet

Comment: thank you so much for your help this code has been very useful and it works too could you possibly tell me how I would tax a user if they were over 18 assuming I already have the variable which calculates tax would I just create an if statement and put the name of the subroutine in there

Comment: You can do that or you can create new method to tax everyone over 18. Its up to you and how you want to format your code. If you have troubles with this create another question. Glad to be of help!

Comment: right so now that I have done that I will create another thing which will be the membership so how will I extract that and then charge suitably as there are two different ways of charging it so for efficiency I would probably remove the input option of the code which I will add to the code above s there a way to extract the specific members

Comment: another item in the list

Comment: if i had added another input for membership how would i edit my code so that under def pulldata() it would pull the membership name and have date time function

Comment: By pulling the position of the the list that first name resides. I think you to do some search on lists in python. Try searching about list positions.