# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' snd 'str'

Tags: python

I am getting an error in Python when I am trying to run my program, what the terminal displays when running:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am trying to write the output of my program to a log file.

The current part of the code that is receiving an error:

```
logfile.write("\n Total number: " + str(count[counter]["count"])) + "\n"
```

'count' is a nested dictionary that holds values. 'counter' is part of my for loop, followed by rest of code.

```
 for counter in count:
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: you are using `+` to concatenate "\n" and the result of logfile.write, which likely is an int, the number of written bytes.

Comment: `+ "\n"` should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: You might consider `print(f'\n Total number: {count[counter]["count"]}', file=logfile)` instead.

Comment: Please share the entire error message as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441035/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str)

Answer (score 1):

"\n" should be inside write function. It is outside the function

Comment: So why that exact message?

Comment: I did'nt see your message @usr2564301

Comment: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Answer (score 1):

The `write()` method returns the number (`int`) of characters written. Since you are appending the newline delimiter `\n` to the return value of the `write()` method, you are getting the error. The newline needs to be included in the method call:

```
logfile.write("\n Total number: " + str(count[counter]["count"]) + "\n")
```