# Pyspark : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning Pyspark and just a beginner. I am getting the error as mentioned in the title.
I have followed similar questions and tried what is mentioned here but still doesn't help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441035/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str

Please find below some of my code snippet

```
age=lines.map(lambda x: x.split(',')[2])
friends=lines.map(lambda x: x.split(',')[3])

rdd=lines.map(lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2]) +","+ int(x.split(',')[3]))


totalsByAge = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
averagesByAge = totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
results = averagesByAge.collect()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I have converted rdd to int while using map but still getting the error as

```
    rdd=lines.map(lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2]) +","+ int(x.split(',')[3]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I also tried removing "+" but not getting the right syntax.

Comment: The error is surely because of the different types of values (int + str + int) that you are trying to add/concatenate. As per what I can understand, you are trying to find the average value present in 4th column (friends) for each value in 3rd column (age), something like a group by on age and then aggregating the friends column to find the average. Is this understanding correct? If not, can you please add what you are trying to achieve with this code? Some sample input and output data would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding integers and strings, which can not be done in python.
You would first have to concat the strings, and then cast them to int.

```
rdd=lines.map(lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2] +","+ x.split(',')[3]))
```

Comment: hello @robert Kossendey, thanks for looking into it. I tried what you said and now i get error as     rdd=lines.map(lambda x: int(x.split(',')[2] +","+ x.split(',')[3]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '33,385'. I searched for the error and "it means that the argument that you passed to int doesn't look like a number" I see that "," is a problem. 33 and 385 is correct. So how do I handle this? If I create 2 RDD's for column 2 and column 3 and convert into int separately, how do I pass the value in map function? Appreciate your help.